# Solving the corresponding semiring equations to derive a rational expression for L( G)

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Let say we have the following grammar G:

```
S -> bA
  -> aB
  -> 1
A -> aA
  -> bB
B -> bA
  -> aB
  -> 1
```

How would i go about solving the corresponding semiring equations to derive a rational  expression for L( G). I would have to start by solving for B.

SO what i have done so far is:

```
S = bA + aB + 1
A = aA + bB
B = bA + aB + 1 

B = b*(aA +1)
A = aA + bb*(aA+1)
  = aA + bb*aA + bb*
  = (a+bb*a)A + bb*
  = (a+bb*a)*bb*
S = b(a+bb*a)*bb* + aB + 1
```

But from there I am not sure what to do, or even if I did the entire thing right. Also, how would I describe L(G)?

Comment: The easiest way would be to notice $S$ and $B$ have the same productions (so they can be unified), and that the language is that of all strings of `a` and `b` with an _even_ number of  `a`, followed by a single `1`. So a regular expression for it would be, for example, `(b*ab*ab*)*1` or `(b|ab*a)*1`

Comment: So, `S=(b*ab*ab*)*1` right? Then i would have to solve for A and sub it into S correct? Sorry Im a visual learner so I need to see how its done.

Comment: x @k-R: Why would you have to "solve for A"? There's no `A` in `(b*ab*ab*)1`.

Comment: oh.... so i would leave S as `(b*ab*ab*)*1` then?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, could you please show me step by step how I would get S. I know that you gave the result, but I need the steps so I can learn how you got to it. Thanks.

Comment: x @k-Rocker: I'm afraid I didn't follow a step-by-step process. I merely imagined the automaton that corresponds to the regular grammar and saw that a `b` never changes the state, and an `a` always flips the state between A and B, so what the automaton does is count whether there's an odd or an even number of `a`s in the input. Then I wrote down a regular expression for that language from scratch. The alternative `(b|ab*a)*1` is a bit closer to the automaton (the subexpression `b|ab*a` represents how one can get from B to B without any intervening B state) but is still constructed _post hoc_.

Comment: Ok, well I actually need a step by step solution that way I can learn how to do it for the future and because it is for an assignment.